# Four word, two part phrase containing 'head empty'

Tags: phrase-requests, idioms, informal-writing

I'm trying to recall this phrase that implies someone is carefree, well-meaning but either not very bright in general or is momentarily mentally vacant (from tiredness perhaps). I may have seen it somewhere used to humourous affect like Tumblr, but I can't remember.

It's for the same meter as phrases like "buy cheap, buy twice" where these some sort of repetition if the same or similar words.

I've tried looking for "heart full, brain empty" or "head empty" and similar but to no avail.

What, if anything, am I thinking of?

Comment: "Empty heads makre the most noise"? (maybe it's not as concise as your thoughts seem to make it)

Comment: "[Eyes Open, Brain Shut](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/eyes-open-brain-shut/)"? This is just a guessing game so I don't see the point in posting as an answer if it's wrong.

Comment: There is the snowclone 'X born, X bred, strong in the arm but weak in the head' ('X' best if a 3-syllable locative such as 'Demeter'). 'Penny wise, pound foolish' is near-isometric with your stanza.

Comment: This *is* a guessing game because there is no more information than that you heard a parallelistic phrase somewhere. There is no other information. It's not even obvious that the phrase was one in common use — a Tumblr post could have said anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for "No thoughts, head empty" (usually written on two lines, as top and bottom meme text). According to [Know Your Meme](https://amp.knowyourmeme.com/memes/no-thoughts-head-empty):

> **No Thoughts Head Empty** is an internet catchphrase used online to express either speechlessness or personal stupidity. The catchphrase has been used as a caption on numerous image macros that feature a character with a blank expression.
>
> [image: Cosmo from Fairly OddParents]

Comment: That's exactly it. I got my self caught up in the two parts being more different than they are.